# Google Feed API for RSS is not showing current events

Tags: javascript, rss, feed

I am attempting to use Google Feed API to display three current event listings for our homepage. This is to circumvent some of the issues we are having with a third part calendar application.

However, with the feed limit set to 3, the only listings that will show up for me are from Jan. 18. Is there a way to make the code show only current or future events?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="feed"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

var feedcontainer=document.getElementById("feed");
var feedurl="http://25livepub.collegenet.com/calendars/publishers-calendar-7.rss";
var feedlimit = 3;
var rssoutput = '';


function rssfeedsetup(){
   var feedpointer=new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl);
   feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit) ;
   feedpointer.load(displayfeed);
}


function displayfeed(result){
  if (!result.error){
     var thefeeds=result.feed.entries;
     for (var i=0; i<thefeeds.length; i++){
        var untrimContent = thefeeds[i].content;
        var trimContent = untrimContent.split("<br>", 2);
        rssoutput+="<div><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></div>" + trimContent;
        feedcontainer.innerHTML=rssoutput;
     } 
   } else {
     feedcontainer.innerHTML = "Error Loading Events";
   }
}


window.onload=function(){
rssfeedsetup();
};
```

Comment: Solved this issue, The settings on the RSS feed were displaying historic values that Google API was displaying.

Comment: i have also the same issue. how do u solve?